# get subset of rows n days forward of index

Tags: pandas

I have a set of indices that match a condition:

```
for col in signal.columns:
    for sign in signs:
        index = signal.index[signal[col] == sign].tolist()
        for i in index:
```

at this point, I would like to look at the range of values for this column at i to i + n days in advance (where n is an integer); something like:

```
            print(signal[col].iloc[i:i + n])
```

however, I cannot add the int to the date i:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
```

Comment: Can you post a sample dummy dataframe with with expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use `dateutil.relativedelta` lib to compute your dates and uisng `.loc[date]` you will be able to locate your row data.

Answer (score 1):

iloc() looks primarily at one row (the 'i' part), where .loc() will give you a slice. See iloc() docs here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html

You should just be able to use your code with .loc instead of iloc, or just a slice. But notice the slight differences in what is returned. My example has a column named 'Open'.

```
i=10
n=5
col = 'Open'


In [38]: print(df[col].loc[i])
1.1778571

In [39]: print(df[col].loc[i:i+n])
10   1.178
11   1.135
12   1.156
13   1.154
14   1.104
15   1.082
Name: Open, dtype: float64

In [40]: print(df[col][i:i+n]) #one less row than inlcuding .loc()
10   1.178
11   1.135
12   1.156
13   1.154
14   1.104
Name: Open, dtype: float64
```